# Linq select returning string instead of object

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following code:

```
var languages = _languageService
            .GetAll()
            .Select(x => (((LanguageViewModel) new LanguageViewModel().InjectFrom(x))))
            .ToList();
```

When executing this, `languages` becomes, as expected, a collection of `LanguageViewModel` objects:

[image: Working]

What I am trying to do is, when selecting, also convert the object's `Code` property to uppercase, as so:

```
var languages = _languageService
            .GetAll()
            .Select(x => (((LanguageViewModel) new LanguageViewModel().InjectFrom(x)).Code = x.Code.ToUpper()))
            .ToList();
```

I'm expecting the `languages` object to have multiple `LanguageViewModel`s in it but it looks like this:

[image]

My guess is the fact that I'm using a statement like `Select(x => (new Object().Property = Value))` it selects the `Property`. But then, how can I return an object with one of its properties changed? Using object initializer before inject is not an option as it gets overriden, using it after the Inject is not possible, as it is not casted yet, so I got to the solution here which does not seem to work. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are selecting just the code.  Consider using a helper method to map/format your object.

Comment: You're already mapping `LanguageViewModel` from `Language` entity using the `InjectFrom()` method. Why not `this.Code = languge.Code.ToUpper()` inside the mapping method instead? That's the whole point of a view-model - that it adapts itself to the specific needs of the view...

Comment: InjectFrom() is a function from Omu.ValueInjecter, a NuGet package specialized in value injecting. Would it be a good idea to change it? I doubt it..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't write the lambda body as a single expression that does what you want, but you don't need to. You can put multiple statements in a lambda:

```
var languages = _languageService
    .GetAll()
    .Select(x => {
        var lvm = (LanguageViewModel)new LanguageViewModel().InjectFrom(x);
        lvm.Code = x.Code.ToUpper();
        return lvm;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: If you're using safe cast, you should also check if `lvm` is not null before going futher. Just saying...

Comment: @Atlasmaybe Good point. I changed it to the same unsafe cast he had originally. BTW a lot of people hear "just saying" as mildly obnoxious. Just sayin'... (/s)

Comment: +1 But, assuming `InjectFrom` is returning a more-abstract (less-specific) type than `LanguageViewModel`, I don't think `(LanguageViewModel)new LanguageViewModel().InjectFrom(x);` will even compile...

Comment: @Ed Plunkett My English is not good enough to use "mildly obnoxious" sentenses, or to make "second degree" sentenses. I was litteraly just saying my comment above. ;)

Comment: @haim770 I wrote a test example that compiles for me.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, Probably because you're attempting to cast `LanguageViewModel` to `LanguageViewModel`. Again, if `InjectFrom()` returns more abstract type, it will fail to compile. And if it does return `LanguageViewModel` then the whole thing is completely redundant.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, You're right that it compiles fine. But it fails at runtime.

Comment: @haim770 This example compiles and runs; if it doesn't correctly illustrate the principle we're discussing, now that we've got a concrete code example, we can figure out where we're talking past each other: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cbonlZ

Comment: @haim770 My assumption in including the cast was that `InjectFrom()` is a overridden virtual whose declared return type is less specialized than the actual runtime type of the object it's returning. Of course, we all know what they say about assumptions.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, Sorry, you're right. There was something wrong in my code that I just noticed.

Comment: Hello, InjectFrom() is actually a method that uses reflection to read into the calling object's type's properties and returns an object of type `Object`. You can continue your debate now. :D

Comment: `I'd love a way to do this with less typing.` ...Well, you *could* create an extension method `T Apply<T>(this T @this, Action<T> a) { a(@this); return @this; }`, then call `foo.Armpit.Apply(a => a.Limpet = 4)` to get `Armpit` with its `Limpet` changed to `4`. Is it worth it? I don't know.

Comment: @31eee384 You're right, that'd work. I don't know if it's worth it either, but maybe I'll kick it around a bit. It's the kind of thing that people would see as a justification for LISP macros, I bet.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Select` line could be rewritten to

```
.Select(x =>
 {
  var vm = new LanguageViewModel().InjectFrom(x);
  vm.Code = vm.Code.ToUpper();
  return vm;
 })
```